# Class constant in CreateJS undefined

Tags: oop, adobe, constants, createjs

I am trying to create a constant named "SPEED" for a "Main" class in Adobe Animate. Below is my code.

```
function Main(){
    this.update.bind(this));
}

Main.SPEED = 3.0;

Main.prototype.update = function(evt){
    console.log("SPEED"+SPEED);
    console.log(5+SPEED);
}
```

The problem is that it displays as undefined.
If I try to do some calculations with it the result is NaN.
The sample of the console feed can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k9F.png).

What would be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined correctly your constant:

```
Main.SPEED = 3.0;
```

But you are not using it. In your code, you defined **Main.SPEED**, but in your `update` function you're using **SPEED**, a variable you haven't defined:

```
Main.prototype.update = function(evt){
    console.log("SPEED"+SPEED); // SPEED is not defined
    console.log(5+SPEED); 
}
```

Try the following code. In this one, I defined your constant, and a `speed` property of the `Main` function, setted to 0. In each tick, the value of the constant is added to the `speed` property.

```
function Main(){
    this.speed = 0;
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.update.bind(this));
}

Main.SPEED = 3.0;

Main.prototype.update = function(evt){
    this.speed += Main.SPEED; 
    console.log("SPEED: " + this.speed);
}

var main = new Main();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very silly mistake from my side. I also found that my variable name should not be identical to the class name (see below), another silly mistake.

    var Main = new Main(); //incorrect.

Comment: That's why you should mantain a naming convention in your code. For example, camelCase for variables and function names (like `main` or `isMoving`), and words with a capital letter for classes names (like `Main`).